# Mimic resources: map same URL to different controller method based on request type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Let's say we want to create an unsubscribe page in Rails.

Is it possible to create a single www.website.com/unsubscribe URL that renders the unsubscribe form on a GET request, but directs to a different controller method upon a form request?

In other words, we want to mimic the default resources functionality but not for something that maps to an ActiveRecord.

We're on Rails 3.2.12.

Comment: What do you mean by form request? POST request?

Comment: yes post request, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

```
get 'subscribe', to: 'controller#unsubscribe_form'
post 'subscribe', to: 'controller#unsubscribe'
```

Comment: cool, thanks! so instead of "match" start with either "get" or "post"?